# Django default model field value

Tags: python, django, django-models

suppose I have a Django object of this type:

```
class Some(Model):
    some_value = CharField(max_length=20)
```

and after a while (and a few objects later) I understood I'd like to save the created time for each new object, so I add the following field:

```
created = FloatField(default=time.time)
```

Let's suppose now I have a few old object which were created without the "created" field. When I query them, they receive the default time.time, even though it's suppose to be None.
How can I get a different value for all the old objects? I only want new objects to be created with this default, and say all old objects without this field to be None, or some other known value. Setting null=True doesn't make a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you had to provide a default value for the old objects when you ran your migrations, right ? If that is true you can check against the default value.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add a `created` field defaulted to now but want to set it to `None` for old rows. You could achive this by making two migrations:

- Add new field and default it to `None`

  ```
    created = FloatField(null=True, default=None)
  ```
- Run `makemigrations`
- Change default value for newer fields:

  ```
    created = FloatField(null=True, default=time.time)
  ```
- Run `makemigrations`
- Run `migrate`

When first migration run, all old rows `created` will be set to `None` (because they don't have a value and default will be used). When seconds migration run old rows will not change because they already has a value. New rows will use the default (`time.time`).

---

### Without migrations

`syncdb` does nothing if table is already created in DB. You should modify your DB manually (i.e. `ALTER TABLE` commands of SQL)

- Modify your DB and add a nullable `created` field with `NULL` as default value.
- Add field to your code (with `default=time.time`)

When you add a new nullable column to DB, all existing rows will set to `NULL` and Django handles default in application level.

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately I'm using an old django version without the migrate option... I'll look it up with syncdb

Comment: Thanks for the info! I should have already said that the database is mongodb... But it was a good opportunity to upgrade the Django version, so it was a win win.